# Cannot Query Salesforce Object

Tags: salesforce, soql, custom-object

I apologize if this is a duplicate issue, but I couldn't find a similar issue. I'm new here.

I have a custom object in Salesforce that cannot be queried. It always times out. It used to do that sometimes, but then it would work. Now, I cannot query it no matter what I do.
I tried:

- Select Id From Object__c (Times out)
- Select Id From Object__c Limit 5 (Times out)
- Select Id From Other_Object__c (This works)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to execute the SOQL query? How many Object__c records are there?

Comment: I tried using the developer console, the Salesforce workbench, and Apex code. There are about 220,000 objects.

Comment: What is the explicit exception you are getting from the developer console? Without an explicit where clause you may be running into selectivity issues. See [Query & Search - Optimization Cheat Sheet](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf)